# Elastic search result filter by user

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I'm using `elasticsearch_dsl` which works great.

However, I would like the results to filter according the the user token that gets sent.

I tried using rest_frameworks' filters, but had no success with it.

What is the right way to achieve this?

## URL to access results

```
http://localhost:9200/_search
```

## Models.py

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', blank=True, null=True)
```

## Search.py

```
from rest_framework import filters
connections.create_connection()

class TaskIndex(DocType):
    title = String()
    class Meta:
        index = 'task-index'

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.filter(owner=request.user)


def bulk_indexing():
    TaskIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Task.objects.all().iterator()))


def _search(title):
    s = Search().filter('term', title=title.text)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

Answer (score -1):

Just modify the `_search` function to filter also by user. I don't know in what format do you store users in ES, but it should be something like:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Q

def _search(title, user):
    s = Search().query('bool', must=[ 
        Q('term', title=title.text),
        Q('match', owner=user.pk),
    ])
    return s.execute()
```

Comment: Thanks- but that still returns all results (not just by user). I want it to hide results unless it is supplied with a owner token

Comment: Try replacing `filter` with `query`.

Comment: Nope, still returns all results

Comment: Print `s.to_dict()` before return to see what is sent to ES.

Comment: I have `print(s.to_dict())` before the return and I'm not seeing it in my django console.

Comment: Then the problem may be that the function is never executed?

Comment: So then I need to filter elsewhere? What more code do you need to see?

Comment: If I understand the question update right, you are accessing ES directly (on port 9200) instead going through Django?

Comment: Correct- I am happy to redirect it via a django URL if that is needed and you can show me

Comment: You should go through Django, but this is out of scope for one answer. Search for tutorials online and than I can help you if you have more precise questions. Maybe this one will work for the start: https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-python-django-frontend-queries